# Django ListView of instances of an attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

learning Django here and have a simple question that I'm struggling with. I'd like to make a page that is a list of the "Billing Month"s of Projects. Currently Project.project_billing_month is simply a CharField. I'd like the HTML page to list the months, i.e. "JAN_2020", "FEB_2020", "MAR_2020", etc, where I can create URLs to click through to a list of projects billed that specific month.

From Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inventory_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    creation_date = models.DateField()
    project_billing_month = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default='JAN_2020')
```

From Views.py:

```
class BillingMonthList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'billing_month_list.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.only().values_list('project_billing_month', flat=True).order_by('-inventory_number')
```

HTML:

```
{% for month in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ month }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your expected and actual output?

Comment: @MeL Updated code with latest attempt, which is closer. Expected Output is a list of each of the Billing Months (e.g. JAN_2020, FEB_2020, etc). One output of each month, which I can turn into a URL to click through to page with all of the Projects from that month. Kind of like a Category list from a blog where you click on a category and see all the posts from that category.

Actual Output is a long list of the Billing Month of each of the project objects.